# What is the purpose of namespace System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am wondering are the classes in this namespace designed to help me to create something like bot to do some tedious work on a particular program UI without any prior deal or help from the program writer? for example can i use **TextPattern** class to control any **win32 TextBlock** on the screen? or the programmer must provide some methods for the automation and this namespace would help me to use those methods.

Else what is purpose of this namespace ?!

Comment: ["Provides support for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) UI Automation clients."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I am sorry i dont that asking for example is forbidden.

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.Windows.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) is **WPF only** programmatic interface to your application's UI. With it, you can access your UI's button etc. from code and invoke them. Its use case is similar to [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and the other web drivers/web automation test tools.

As mentioned, it's WPF only so you can use it if you're using WPF and if you can live with the requirements:

> To support UI automation, a control author needs to implement an abstract class AutomationPeer

The most complete how-to tutorial is available from CodeProject: [Automate your UI using Microsoft Automation Framework.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141842/Automate-your-UI-using-Microsoft-Automation-Framew)